# Javascript geolocation not finding location information

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, openstreetmap

I'm currently trying to implement a simple map using javascript, openstreetmaps and leaflet.

My problem comes way before that, when calling javascripts geolocation, and confirming the information on the browser I keep getting an error. My current code is the following:

```
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css"
integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ=="
crossorigin=""/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"
integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log=="
crossorigin=""></script>

<style>
   #mymap {
       width: 100%;
       height: 400px;
       background-color: grey;
       margin-top: 15px;
   }
</style>

<script language="javascript">

function initmap(initialLat, initialLong)
{
   if(!initialLat || !initialLat.length){
   initialLat = 38.01693;
}

if(!initialLong || !initialLong.length){
  initialLong = -8.69475;
}

var mymap = this.mymap = L.map('mymap',{
    center: [initialLat, initialLong],
    zoom: 15
    });

var osmUrl='http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
var osmAttrib='Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';

L.tileLayer(osmUrl, osmAttrib).addTo( mymap );
}

function getMylocation()
{
    if(navigator.geolocation){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;

        mymap.setView(new L.LatLng(lat, long), 15);

    }, function (error) {
      switch (error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          output.innerHTML += "<p>User denied the request for Geolocation.</p>";
          break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
          output.innerHTML += "<p>Location information is unavailable.</p>";
          break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
          output.innerHTML += "<p>The request to get user location timed out.</p>";
          break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
          output.innerHTML += "<p>An unknown error occurred.</p>";
          break;
      }
    });
  }
}

</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="javascript:initmap();">

<button id="find-near-btn" onClick="getMylocation()">
  Find my location
</button>   

<div id="mymap"></div>
<div id="output"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

When calling the getMyLocation() function using the button, I always end up in the

```
case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
```

condition. Any idea on why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is called when position information is unavailable. GeoLocation API estimates location on the basis of CELL Towers, Wifi MAC Addresses, GPS (if on mobile). But the information is not available. Your code is correct, try running that on different device.